# Android GridLayout different span count based on row width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a recyclerview with GridLayoutManager as layout managar and what I want to achieve is like image below

[image]

As you can see every row may have multiple item just based on item width and each item is a TextView with `wrap_content` width but all item have same height.
I know it is possible to set row span by `SpanSizeLookup` but for doing that, I should know the count of spans before while my list rows will fill just by items width
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with grid layout manager. it seems that you need something like `FlowLayoutManager`.

Comment: `FlowLayoutManager` was good too and will suitable for my purpose but flexbox-layout is supported by google and seems better, but anyway thanks for your response

Comment: yeah, actually I meant `FlexBoxLayoutManager` but I made a mistake in the name!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might be better off with a different Layout manager like FlexboxLayoutManager https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

It has lots of flexibility of on controlling when the wrap the row (automatic or manual) and you can specify lots of controls on how individual cells can grow/shrink to fill a line.

There are lots of examples on the github page.

But as a starting point you could manually wrap before cells 3 and 7 to give you the 3 on the first row and 4 on the second.

Or setting FlexWrap will do it automatically based on size

Comment: You just finished hours of research... Thank you so much !
Why this question and this answer doesn't have hundreds of upvote ???????